# Filter only the needed duplicate records from List of Objects java (version less than 8)

Tags: java

I have to filter the duplicates from list of objects which is pretty easy. But, here I have an internal condition while filtering the duplicates. Here is my code.

```
List<Person> personsList = Arrays.asList(
                new Person(ID: 1234, dateOfJoin: new Date("2020-08-31 17:32:46"), status: 'Accepted'),
                new Person(ID: 1234, dateOfJoin: new Date("2020-08-31 17:30:49"), status: 'Rejected'),
                new Person(ID: 3456, dateOfJoin: new Date("2020-08-29 13:23:34"), status: 'Waiting'));
```

I have to filter the personsList **where ID is equal and I have to get the most recent dateOfJoin** person. So, my final filtered list would be like the following.

```
List<Person> filteredPersonsList = Arrays.asList(
                    new Person(ID: 1234, dateOfJoin: new Date("2020-08-31 17:30:49"), status: 'Rejected'),
                    new Person(ID: 3456, dateOfJoin: new Date("2020-08-29 13:23:34"), status: 'Waiting'));
```

How could I filter this? Any suggestions please?

Thanks.

Comment: Group by `ID`, sort result list by `dateOfJoin`, pick first in each bucket

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? any code samples?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are corresponding getters look like this.

```
    Collection<Person> result = personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                     Person::getId,
                     Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                         Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getDateOfJoin),
                         Optional::get)))
        .values();
```

Unfortunately, `maxBy` returns `Optional` and needs further unwrapping

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toMap` and `maxBy` to get max `dateOfJoin` with same id and take values of the map in an ArrayList.

```
List<Person> filteredPersonsList = 
        new ArrayList<>(personsList
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getID, Function.identity(),
                    BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getDateOfJoin))))
              .values());
```

Comment: great minds think alike ;)